# Docker: Container not reachable after logout

Tags: windows, hyper-v, docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

I have installed Docker Desktop on a Windows Server 2016. I have used the official docker installer. Everything works fine until I log out of my windows user. If I log out none of my docker container can be reached anymore (via the published ports). If I log in again the container are still not reachable. Docker also can't download new images from the internet then. I have to restart the docker service manually. Then every thing works fine until I log out again.

Any ideas?